# Off center a variable width table

Tags: css, html-table, center

I center a variable width table with css as:

```
#article {width=1000px}
table.center {margin: 0 auto}

<div id="article">
<table class="center">
.....
</table>
</div>
```

But in this case I like to **off center** this table a bit to the left.
Be aware that the width of this table is variable.
The center of the table must be on `40%` off the div it's in.
Suppose in case below the table has a width  `200px`.
Normally while centering it has `400px` space on the left and right side. 
But now I like to have `300px` at the left and `500px` at the right of the table.

```
#article {width=1000px}
table.offcenter20left { ??? }

<div id="article">
<table class="offcenter20left">
....
</table>
</div>
```

What CSS code do I need to off-center this table?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `table` with a `div` and use relative positioning:

```
<div class="center-outer">
  <table class="center-inner">
    <!-- ... -->
  </table>
</div>
```

The accompanying CSS:

```
.center-outer {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  left: 40%;
}

.center-inner {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  left: -50%;
}
```

`.center-inner` shifts the `table` to the left by `50%` of its own width, centering it along where its left edge would normally be. `.center-outer` then pushes both the `div` and the `table` to the right by `40%` of the `div`'s parent's width, effectively centering the table at `40%`.

If you intend to center more than just the `table` within the same parent, it would be simpler to use 2 wrappers; then it's not necessary to attach `.center-inner` to each child:

```
<div class="center-outer">
  <div class="center-inner">
    <table>
      <!-- ... -->
    </table>
    <p>
      <!-- ... -->
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: only minor issue I see is if the content of the table stretches to >60% of the containing div, your wrapper will stretch beyond the bounds of the containing div.

Comment: Thanks Nikita for your input and James for making me aware of possible trouble...

Comment: Good point, @JamesMontagne. Are there any possible consequences of that? Unless you have CSS rules that unintentionally affect the wrappers, I don't believe any problems could arise, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is causing a horizontal scrollbar where it doesn't seem to be needed.

Answer (score 1):

With the use of a wrapper, you could use a negative margin.  This supports percent values and will allow it to be dynamic.

### HTML

```
<div class="article">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <table class="offcenter20left">
      <tr>
        <td>.....</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
table.offcenter20left {
  margin:0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
  margin-left:-20%; /* adjust as desired */
}
```

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/8Gas6/3
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8Gas6/3/show

Comment: In this case the negative margin would be 2 times the amount you wanted to offset from 50% right?  So in the example `margin-left` should be `-20%`?

Comment: @JamesMontagne Thanks for pointing that out.  For me it's just laziness at the moment. :P  I had to code an HTML email that looks decent in Outlook 2007 today, so I feel entitled to be a little lazy at the moment.

Comment: Thanks!You are right
it must be offcenter10left indeed!
As James stated It will come in trouble if the width of the table is too big. I didn't thougt of that. 
Have to think about that...
So far thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

With `CSS3 Calc` you can perform the math dynamically:

```
margin-left: calc(40% - 50px);
```

(Assuming the half of the pixels in your example, to make it works on jsFiddle with smaller screens too: 500 total pixels, a table of 100px width)

(50px in the calc() is the half of your table size)

http://jsfiddle.net/u4Haa/

Comment: intresting, but the 50px I assume is half of the table size?
Point is: it must work with every table size (normally I ommit the size). So the 50px is not known... Can be anything.
And to make things more worse (and I didn't realize this till a few minutes ago): if the table grows in width it may not overflow at the left side...

Comment: Absolutely, you should use calc() when you know the dimensions... (I've been fooled by the pixels specified in your question, while the title clearly says dynamic width, my fault :)